How to run and debug WSO2 API Manager source code in IntelliJ IDEA?
I would like to contribute to the development of WSO2 API Manager by working on some issues. However, I am facing challenges in setting up the project to run and debug the source code in IntelliJ IDEA.

What are the steps to properly configure and run the WSO2 API Manager source code in IntelliJ IDEA?

How can I configure IntelliJ to debug WSO2 API Manager? Is there any specific setup or configuration required for this?

Are there any specific dependencies or tools I need to install to get started?



You can start the wso2 server as follows.
sh wso2server.sh -debug 5005

Configure remote debugging in Intellij as follows and start in debug mode.

You can find more details in https://anuradha-15.medium.com/remote-debugging-wso2-products-using-intellij-idea-ide-c0e828abd700
